# ReferenceError: API is not defined (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I'm trying to make an App for meteo, but my api doesn't load.
When i call API in fetch it output: ReferenceError: API is not defined
It is my first app (also my first question on StackOverflow), this is the snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
  let long;
  let lang;
  let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector('.temperature-description');
  let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector('.temperature-degree');
  let locationTimezone = document.querySelector('.location-timezone');
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const proxy = 'https://cors-anyware.herouapp.com/';
      const API = '${proxy}https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=cc6a4a00070dfbee1327390b072f88d6/${lat},${long}';
    });
    fetch(API).then(response=>{
      return response.json();
    }).then(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      const {
        temperature,
        summary
      }
      = data.currently;
      //set DOM elements from the API
      temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature;
    });
  };
}
);
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: You declare `API` variable in the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method scope. Declare it outside and your `fetch` call should be able to access it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1169798

Answer (score 0):

Your `API` constant variable is block scoped, it means that it is accessible only inside of callback of getCurrentPosition function.

And also,`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, you should call `fetch` inside the callback.  otherwise `fetch` will execute before location lat lon is detected by browser.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
  let long;
  let lang;
  let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector('.temperature-description');
  let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector('.temperature-degree');
  let locationTimezone = document.querySelector('.location-timezone');
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      const proxy = 'https://cors-anyware.herouapp.com/';
      const API = '${proxy}https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=cc6a4a00070dfbee1327390b072f88d6/${lat},${long}';

      fetch(API).then(response=>{
          return response.json();
      }).then(data=>{
          console.log(data);
          const {
            temperature,
            summary
          }
         = data.currently;
        //set DOM elements from the API
        temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature;
      });
    });

  };
}
);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but in load give  an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: that's  JSON parsing error, check the api response. if it's not in valid JSON format. your `response.json()` will fail in the first `then` block of `fetch` call. add a console statement before `response.json()` and check what's being consoled.

Comment: is it possible that they did not activate my API? Response is:   Response { type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:5500/firstApp/$%7Bproxy%7Dhttps://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=cc6a4a00070dfbee1327390b072f88d6/${lat},${long}", redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
​

Comment: I think somethig is wrong with the endpoint, check that first.